# Wordpress Theme Customize doesn't save changes

Tags: database, theme-customizer

The preview works fine, it's just that changes are not applied, I guess it should be cause an database error.

I recently migrated the website from a hosting to a VPS and the SQL import gave me some errors, the whole database size in .sql is 270MB with 88027 entries in `wp_posts`

Most of the tables after the importation lack of primary key and there were multiple rows with ID 0, I already "fixed" it deleting these rows (they all seemed to be irrelevant) and setting primary key to every table.

It didn't fixed my issue so I tried now repairing database with WordPress, defining `wp_allow_repair` to `wp-config.php` and going to `wp-admin/maint/repair.php`, neither worked so I repaired every table from PHPMyAdmin, again, neither worked.

I also tried overwriting all wordpress files but no luck.

**error.log:**

> .[Thu Feb 23 15:32:13 2017] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] WordPress
>   database error Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' for query INSERT
>   INTO `wp_posts` (`post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`,
>   `post_content`, `post_contet_filtered`, `post_title`, `post_excerpt`,
>   `post_status`, `post_type`, `comment_status`, `ping_status`,
>   `post_password`, `post_name`, `to_ping`, `pinged`, `post_modified`,
>   `post_modified_gmt`, `post_parent`, `menu_order`, `post_mme_type`,
>   `guid`) VALUES (1, '2017-02-23 14:32:12', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '{\n
>   \"generate_settings[post_content]\": {\n        \"value\":
>   \"excerpt\",\n        \"type\": \"option\",\n
>   \"user_id\": 1\n   }\n}', '', '', '', 'auto-draft',
>   'customize_changeset', 'closed', 'closed', '',
>   '8039b052-4558-4b93-ad93-debbb7a2b103', '', '', '2017-02-23 14:32:12',
>   '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '', '') made by
>   do_action('wp_ajax_customize_sve'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array,
>   WP_Customize_Manager->save, WP_Customize_Manager->save_changeset_post,
>   wp_insert_post, referer:
>   https://domain.com/wp-admin/customize.php?return=%2Fwpadmin%2F&changeset_uuid=8039b052-4558-4b93-ad93-debbb7a2b103

Comment: unlikely to be related to anything in your DB. check you php error log

Comment: Right, forgot to check it, there is what it throws

Comment: seems like a bug with the costumizer changeset feature. I changed the tag to hopefully get weston notified of this question, but you might want to open a bug in wordpress bug trac for it.

Answer (score 0):

Damn, the error was pretty intuitable: most tables in my database lacked of `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Since ID is not defined in the INSERT query, it will be 0 unless `AUTO_INCREMENT` is setted to ID.

So I just fixed it by setting `AUTO_INCREMENT`